# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed line 85

Tags: php, wordpress

To start off, thanks to anyone for the help here. I have **VERY** basic coding knowledge. Enough to read and somewhat understand but all from a 15+ year old high school programming class. Zero experience with PHP. That being said I am confident that I can put in code if explained why this broke.

I am asking this question here because the developer of the wordpress plugin I want to use has stop responding (6 months ago) to questions regarding the plugin.

So here goes. I get this error....

**Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/nexumgam/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitch-status/includes/twitch-status-options.php on line 85**

```
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="width: 30px"><button class="button button-primary"       type="button" style="' . ($first?'display: none':'') . '" onclick="twitchStatus_RemoveChannelRow(this)">X</button></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="twitch_status_channels[names][]" size="40" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($channel['name']) . '" /></td>';
    //ERROR OCCURS HERE (I THINK, as the next line is 85)
    echo '<td><textarea class="large-text code" name="twitch_status_channels[selectors][]" cols="40" rows="3">' . htmlspecialchars(implode("\n", $channel['selectors'])) . '</textarea></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $first = false;
}
```

Incase you need it for any info I may have failed to provide here is the link to the plug-in - https://wordpress.org/plugins/twitch-status/

Thanks again for any help!

--PS. APOLOGIZES apparently nothing I do in the comments allows me to do code that I can figure out and I can only edit it for 5 minutes.

Comment: $channel['selectors'] contains array or not please check it first.

Comment: check if $channel['selectors'] is an array or not, use **print_r($channel['selectors']);** and see what it returns.

Comment: So looking at the code seems that it is any array, Not sure how IF statements work in PHP but it looks like it is wrapped in one. I didn't see somewhere that closed the IF statement unless it is the code 
'$first = false;'
That being said line 85 that is failing is within the if statement. Here is the code that makes me think it is an array.
' if (empty($channels))
  $channels[] = array('name' => '', 'selectors' => '');

 echo '<table id="twitchStatusChannels">';'

Comment: ` if (empty($channels))
  $channels[] = array('name' => '', 'selectors' => '');

 echo '<table id="twitchStatusChannels">';`